# Accessing Google API by initializing properly the AdWordsUser object

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am new to Google API.

I need to access Adword Offline Conversion API through .NET code.

In theory this is pretty easy since all the .NET code that implements [this knowledge](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/importing-conversions) is provided here:
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dotnet-lib/blob/master/examples/AdWords/CSharp/v201406/AdvancedOperations/UploadOfflineConversions.cs

In practice we need to get logged to google API (through the protocol OAuth 2.0 I guess?) and I didn't found any good documentation about this. There are these two documentations, but no clear tutorial:

- [Using OAuth 2.0 to Access Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2)
- [Google APIs Client Library for .NET](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/dotnet/guide/aaa_oauth)

It looks like I need to create a project at https://console.developers.google.com, then Enable an API (which one?).

It looks like I need to set at least all these settings (through code or through `App.Config` file) and also manage some tokens expirations:

```
AdWordsUser adWordsUser = new AdWordsUser();
AdWordsAppConfig adWordsUserConfig = (AdWordsAppConfig) adWordsUser.Config;
adWordsUserConfig.ClientCustomerId = "123-456-7890"; 
adWordsUserConfig.OAuth2Mode = ? APPLICATION or SERVICE_ACCOUNT ?
adWordsUserConfig.DeveloperToken = "????"; // MUST BE SET
adWordsUserConfig.OAuth2RefreshToken =  "????";
adWordsUserConfig.OAuth2ClientId =  "????";
adWordsUserConfig.OAuth2ClientSecret =  "????";
```

But I have no idea how to obtain all these IDs?

Thanks

---

Edit:

After activating the API *Ad Exchange Buyer API* (no idea if this is the one required) I have been able to obtain some ID for credential.

While this give me what to put for: OAuth2ClientId,  OAuth2ClientSecret I am still laking a lot of info to get started.

[image]

Comment: Nuget client lib: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.AdWords/  I have a tutorial that uses Google Drive with a sample project at the bottom.  It might help you understand the Oauth2.  http://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/

Comment: Linda, your blog post tutorial looks very promising but you are not using https://github.com/googleads/googleads-dotnet-lib (which sounds normal since you are targeting Drive). So I don't have access to types like GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync or UserCredential. Is "Ad Exchange Buyer" API the right one to upload Offline Conversion? How to map settings I got to adWordsUserConfig settings? How to deal with token lifetime? Thanks

Comment: I haven't actually played with the adwords API, I assume that its like the other Google APIs.  with the exception that it appears to be soap / xml.  I don't have access to any adwords accounts so its hard for me to help more, because I cant play with it myself.   email me if you want maybe we can figure it out together.

Comment: Sounds like I need first to register this way: https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/signingup  Google is definitely not doing things easy for its clients :/

Comment: there are test accounts maybe I can play with this.  Looks like you need to apply now takes a week before you will hear from them. https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/test-accounts

Comment: Facing the same issues, if you figured this out, would be awesome if you could answer your own question :)

Comment: No w'er not done yet :(